# QR decoding barcode output symbols meaning

Tags: encoding, ascii, barcode, decode, qr-code

I have this output of a decoded QR barcode, does this code has a meaning or can I interpret these symbols to a meaningful output? Is there any algorithm to interpret the output of decoding QR?
output: LWludGVydmlldy5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This string:

```
LWludGVydmlldy5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tL
```

is a **Base64** representation of:

```
-interview.s3.amazonaws.com
```

However, this is **not** related to QR Codes. The person who created that QR Code arbitrarily decided to encode its content as Base64.

If you're managing Base64-encoded QR Codes, you'll need to decode it using the same algorithm, but keep in mind this is not part of the process of decoding QR Codes.