# How to get details from QR code?

Tags: url, qr-code

I got a string from a qr generated image. But how can I get URL out of it. The string I got is the following.

aHR0cDovL2R1Yml6emxlLWludGVydmlldy5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tLzg3M2FhMTA5LnR4dA==

Can anybody help me to get all the information out of it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322803/qr-decoding-barcode-output-symbols-meaning

Answer (score 4):

That string is encoded in [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). The decoded version of your string is:

`http://dubizzle-interview.s3.amazonaws.com/873aa109.txt`

If you need to integrate this into your software, find a library that has a Base64 decoder to decode such strings.